# DM is making rules without reason, how can I stop this

Tags: house-rules

My DM is a beginner, she does not know the basics very well. I am playing a game where I am inside a camp with creatures that can give you almost any food that you want (We're doing this game off of a campaign). My character like to eat human but they won't serve that to me, it's against they're policy, so I ask for monkey. The DM quickly gets agitated and says "They don't serve monkey, you're not understanding they only get food people actually eat.", right then me and my D'n'D buddy both tell her that in some places monkey is a delicacy. She get angry and says "Well I am DM and I make up the rules not you so you can follow my rules or get out of the game." I get upset with thee choices I am given and decide to defend myself instead. We get really far into the argument and she says "I am DM I decide the rules the camp doesn't serve monkeys or **any** endangered species.". I get upset when I hear that and I finally ask "Why, why can we not have endangered species? Please tell me why because I'm very curious and I would like to know why. I'm pretty sure people would ask for very strange foods in this camp with different types of people.", a long silence is there. She then says that she has to go.

This is not the only time she has made a tiny stupid rule that makes no sense at all and it has gotten a little worst, she basically just uses "because I'm DM" for everything. Can someone help me to keep me in the game but make loop holes to get her upset and her rules almost useless?

Comment: What edition is this for?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22715/is-there-a-limit-to-rule-0

Comment: Also, does this problem cover narrative arguments or mechanical arguments?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what your question is. Do you want to discourage your GM from making rules? Setting details? Are you looking for loopholes to avoid her rulings? Or loopholes to get her upset (which seems an odd request, but it's what the final line of your question's body seems to ask for)? I'm voting to put this question on hold until it can be clarified.

Comment: @GMJoe Wow, ninja'ed. I was just typing almost exactly the same thing. Although I was also going to ask about the question in the title; making up rules for situations the existing rules don't cover is one of the primary purposes of the GM. Are you really looking to prevent this?

Answer (score 49):

What you're describing isn't "the DM made up a rule". They didn't make up any rules at all.

What you're describing is the fact the DM created some people in the world you're playing in, and decided how they worked. This is basically what the DM is there to do in D&D. Your DM decided they didn't eat human or monkey.

Presumably, the DM isn't comfortable with themes of human-eating or monkey-eating, and didn't want that to be a part of those peoples' cultures. This is probably [one of their lines](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/what-do-the-terms-lines-and-veils-mean) they don't want to cross.

My suggestion is: take this as a hint that playing out this character trait may make your DM uncomfortable. Instead of getting agitated with them that you *cannot eat people or monkeys* (which is not really that outrageous a thing for people to not want to do), and complaining, take some steps to maintain their level of comfort.

You can start by saying: "Ok, sure," when they say a culture doesn't eat people.

Then continue play with them.

Your DM may be partially responsible for helping *you* to have fun, but *you* are also responsible for *your DM* having fun. And, generally, you're also responsible for not being a jerk to them when they aren't comfortable following through with themes you want to pursue. The fact they packed up and left is a sign you didn't follow through with your responsibility here.

If you want to continue playing with this person, I suggest that you apologise to her for making her uncomfortable, and that you offer to make the "likes eating human and monkey" character trait mysteriously vanish so that the game doesn't involve themes she's uncomfortable with.