# Half-orc cavalier, A lance seems rather un-orcish, Alternate item?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat, half-orc

Currently a half-orc fighter 4 (Cavalier) and my DM told me i'll finally be getting a mount in the next module. From what i've read, a lance is basically the best weapon on a mount. But i feel it seems rather un-orcish (my character was raised in the orc community more than human). Currently using a maul and two handaxes.

Is it unreasonable to ask my DM about a possible Horseman's pick weapon where it would be 1D12 or 1D10 bludgeoning but also had the special properties of the lance so i can use it one handed while mounted? purpose is that having a shield for that +2 ac would be invaluable.

I **know** i should disucss this with my DM, but i'll only be seeing him in a week and he's really busy with other things (exams) at the moment and i should try to only contact him after his exams and when we actually meet for D&D.

Just want to know if what i'm proposing sounds reasonable.

Comment: define reasonable

Comment: There is a reason why nothing but the lance has the benefits and it's probably for balance. So, changing anything up might cause imbalance.

Comment: Dunno, [this](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=uqP6GJqH&id=EA760D7883B25C9CC5A224C473A79747E3E848B1&thid=OIP.uqP6GJqHmUo1I6ukcEx7KAHaHa&mediaurl=http%3a%2f%2fimg1.wikia.nocookie.net%2f__cb20130704060109%2ffinalfantasy%2fimages%2fc%2fce%2fHeavyLance-ffxii.png&exph=511&expw=511&q=lance&simid=608032028299297714&selectedIndex=0&ajaxhist=0) looks pretty "Orcish" to me, although I assume you are referring to the medeival knight type lance. I would not suggest getting stuck in the European way of thinking and look at cultural equivalents from around the world.

Comment: Oi! 'Ose been sayin' dat Warboss Crunchabonez's Lances be un-Orkish? Why, I'll haff ta teach ya a coupa t'ings! Ay, Squig! Grab me Squiggoth! We gotta teach dis runt some mannas!

Comment: Related: [Can the DM forbid my character from using certain weapons because he “doesn't like them”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68179/4563) since the DM in question felt polearms weren’t sufficiently “barbarian-like” and many answers chose to focus on that misconception, which might be useful information for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Changing the damage type from piercing to slashing or bludgeoning doen't meaningfully impact balance

There are a number of damage types that are better than other damage types.  For example, force damage is almost never resisted or ignored.  Nonetheless, piercing, slashing, and bludgeoning weapons are all about equal in utility and there's no balance-based reason why a certain weapon would be allowed dealing 1d12 piercing but not 1d12 slashing or 1d12 bludgeoning.  If all you are changing is that and the name, there shouldn't be any issue with balance.

Comment: Seems good, i'll have a good chat with my DM about this then. Thanks yall. I was under the impression that the difference was about as big as the weapon triangle in fire emblem. New player here haha

Answer (score 7):

### Use an “orcish elf-sticker”.

This is mechanically exactly like a lance but it has a cooler name and looks totally awesome (providing you have a totally awesome imagination).

Comment: just like reskin the weapon but it functions like a lance huh, but having a cavalry axe do piercing damage would be strange.

Comment: Dont make it an axe then. Surely orcs in your Setting have learned that stabbing things is a good way to injure said thing?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an "orcish" looking lance you could always theme it as something big and clumsy looking that still pierces, like [the ones these games workshop orcs carry](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/Orruk-Boarboys). It's a fantasy setting, they don't need to fit the stereotypes for real world lance designs.

Alternately the dark wanderer's point seems reasonable, it shouldn't be a huge deal just changing damage type if everything else is identical.