# Does the yuan-ti action option Polymorph into Snake require concentration? What is its duration?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, concentration, duration, yuan-ti

In *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, the Yuan-Ti ["Unusual Abilities"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#UnusualAbilities) section (p. 98) lists a number of action options that might be given to high-ranking yuan-ti, one of which is:

> ***Polymorph into Snake (Abomination or Malison Only; Recharge 6).*** The yuan-ti targets a creature it can see within 60 feet of it. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be transformed into a Tiny poisonous snake, as if affected by the *polymorph* spell. The save DC is the same as that of the yuan-ti's Innate Spellcasting ability.

It's not stated that you cast *polymorph*; it says that the target is under the effect of the spell.
So how I should interpret this? Does it require the yuan-ti to maintain concentration? What is its duration?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

### Its duration, including whether it requires concentration, is unspecified.

Polymorph Into Snake imitates the *effect* of Polymorph, not any other aspect of it, and duration is not part of a spell's effect.

[Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell):

> Each spell description begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, **and duration**. *The rest of a spell entry* describes **the spell's effect**.

Then, under "Duration":

> A spell's duration is the length of time the spell persists. A duration can be expressed in rounds, minutes, hours, or even years. Some spells specify that their effects last until the spells are dispelled or destroyed.
>
> ...
>
> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.
>   If a spell must be maintained with concentration, **that fact appears in its Duration entry**, and the spell specifies how long you can concentrate on it. You can end concentration at any time (no action required).

Therefore it has no specific duration and may or may not require concentration.

Comment: The spell effect refers to the duration, how does this answer solve that problem? "The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies."

Comment: @Akixkisu If someone has table experience with handling spells that don't specify a duration, I would welcome their input.

Comment: @MarkWells Point of clarification: you saying that you are arguing that the ability here isn't actually a spell just mimics one right?

Comment: The yuan-ti uses innate spellcasting (MM 309 for malison and abomb type)
"When a character casts any spell, the same basic rules are followed, regardless of the character’s class or the spell’s Effects." So your argument is that the yuan-ti indeed does not cast a spell with its Innate Spellcasting ability, but instead has an ability that only uses the DC of its Innate Spellcasting? So the XGtE (86) invalid target rule (expanding on the basic rules as one of the 10 rules in XGtE that aren't optional) also does not apply because it is not a spell?

Comment: If that is the case you may want to add that to your argument, including "High-ranking yuan-ti might have one or more of the following abilities, either replacing or augmenting what a normal yuan-ti can do." and add how that does not clarify the type of ability as Innate Spellcasting even if it looks like one, quacks like one, and swims like one.

Comment: I'm in agreement with the points Akixkisu's has raised. I fail to see how you've managed to ignore the duration with respect to this: *as if affected by the polymorph spell.* It doesn't say effect, it says affect, and no they aren't synonyms. Affect is a verb, it's an action that occurs. Effect is a noun, it's the description of what's occurring. Since it's **affected** by the polymorph spell in the description of the ability, it means everything from polymorph applies. If it had the same effect as a polymorph spell that would mean it was simply transformed. So yeah, effect =/= affect.'

Comment: @Rubiksmoose My point is that it isn't actually the _Polymorph_ spell. It affects the target as _Polymorph_ would (that is, has the same effect) but it doesn't have the spell's other characteristics, such as level, range, components, or duration.

Comment: That's the contention though Mark. How did you come to that determination? Because if I cast *Dispel* on the target, you'd have to roll or upcast it to end the effect since *Polymorph* is a 4th level spell.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Strictly speaking, you _can't_ dispel this, since it's not a spell.

Comment: @MarkWells - The description literally states that it's: "as if the target is affected by the *polymorph* spell." There's no wiggle room in that wording. Further to that, the Yuan-Ti is using innate spellcasting which is something else the skill states. Innate Spellcasting is still Spellcasting, it's simply innate.

Answer (score 2):

### *Polymorph into Snake* has a duration of up to 1 hour based on concentration.

From the VGtM yuan-ti Action Option Traits (98):

> The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be transformed
>   into a Tiny **poisonous snake**, as if affected by the [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell.

Taking 1 action (it is an action-option), the yuan-ti uses their (unusual) ability *Polymorph into Snake*. The target of the transformation of *Polymorph into Snake* is as if affected by the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell.

For the target to remain polymorphed the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell requires concentration by the caster of the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell. In this case, that is the creature that uses of *Polymorph into Snake* because of the reductio ad absurdum that if the yuan-ti is not treated as the caster, then the effect would immediately end due to the requirement of the caster maintaining concentration for the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell.

[Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) (PHB 203):

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to keep
>   their magic active. If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.
>
> If a spell must be maintained with concentration, that fact appears in
>   its Duration entry, and the spell specifies how long you can
>   concentrate on it. You can end concentration at any time (no action
>   required).

If the target is affected as if it was under the effect of [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph), (PHB 266), :

> Duration: Concentration, up to 1 hour
>
> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops
>   to 0 hit points or dies.

then the duration relies on maintaining concentration. That duration is up to 1 hour based on concentration. In other words:

The transformation lasts for the duration, the duration is concentration of up to an hour or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies.

The yuan-ti may choose to not maintain concentration in that case the transformation ends because maintaining concentration is one of the two conditions for a lasting transformation according to the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell.

If it had a different duration, then the trait would explicitly say that the duration was different, but it does not - in fact, it explicitly says that the target is affected as if affected by the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell with the restriction that it is transformed into a tiny Poisonous Snake (MM 334) and that the save DC is the same as that of the yuan-ti 's Innate Spellcasting ability.

> The save DC is the same as that of the yuan-ti 's Innate Spellcasting
>   ability.

Similarily the (unusual) ability *Snake Antipathy*:

> ***Snake Antipathy (Abomination or Malison Only; Recharge 6).*** The yuan-ti targets a creature it can see within 60 feet of it. The target
>   must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or feel an intense urge to avoid
>   snakes and snakelike creatures (including yuan-ti); as if affected by
>   the antipathy effect of an [*antipathy/sympathy*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antipathy-sympathy) spell. The save DC is
>   the same as that of the yuan-ti's Innate Spellcasting ability.

follows the duration logic that is tied to the [*Antipathy/Sympathy*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antipathy-sympathy) spell (PHB 214) which has a duration of 10 days and does not require concentration for maintaining the effect.

The *Sticks to Snakes* action-option of the yuan-ti explicitly states a duration in its description because the logic of the duration is not tied to the logic of the duration of a spell, it states explicitly:

> The swarm remains for l minute, after which it turns back into the
>   original materials.

This makes it explicit that *Snake Antipathy* doesn't require maintaining concentration and has a duration of 1 minute.

---

### The alternative rulings.

1. The same approach, The yuan-ti is not treated as if they are the caster:
   *Polymorph into Snake* takes 1 action. The yuan-ti is not treated as if they are the caster of a [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell. There is no caster that can maintain the concentration required for the [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell, so *Polymorph into Snake* immediately ends.

> If you lose concentration, such a spell ends.

2. A different approach, there is no duration (specified). There is no duration (specified), so *Polymorph into Snake* immediately ends.

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops
>   to 0 hit points or dies.

3. A different approach, there is no duration specified. The DM decides the rules, aka [DM fiat applies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31794/what-is-gm-dm-fiat). The DM will decide whether maintaining concentration is required and how long it will last (PHB 6):

> Ultimately, the Dungeon Master is the authority on the campaign and
>   its setting, even if the setting is a published world.

In the case of ruling three, read the first part of my answer for guidance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95804/discussion-on-answer-by-akixkisu-does-the-yuan-ti-action-option-polymorph-into-s).

Answer (score 0):

### The problem here is people mistaking the difference between Affect and Effect, and that you asked two questions instead of one.

**Affect** is a verb, it's something that is being done.

**Effect** is a noun, it's what is occurring.

Example: If I toast my bread, I'm affecting my meal by introducing heat to cook the bread to a desired state. The effect is that I have toast. The toast is the effect of what happened when I affected it with heat.

In the case of the Yuan-Ti ability, it states:

> as if **affected** by the polymorph spell

Which means the *Polymorph* spell is affecting the target. That the ability specifically requires the target be turned into a Snake is simple specific > general rules. The important part is that everything within the spell *Polymorph* is applied to the target.

So, for your questions:

**Does the Yuan-Ti need to concentrate on this ability?**

This is going to require DM adjudication. This particular ability is located in the section detailed as Unusual Abilities, which are unique and weird abilities individuals possess that make them different from everything else. A caster not requiring to concentrate on a specific spell through the use of an ability would be a great example of this, and has a lot of mythological backing in the case of a Medusa. There are spells which have the same effect as her ability, although the way it affects a target are vastly different. The important point is that no part of her *Petrifying Gaze* ability makes mention to it affecting a target as if under the effects of any spell.

This is telling. To me, this says very clearly that when an ability references a spell, it's meant to be treated as that spell with any other specific over-rides detailed in the ability being used.

Since the Yuan-Ti ability makes no mention of Concentration being exempt, I would logically conclude that it is not.

Which leads me to your second question:

**What is it's duration?**

This part is actually answered in the spell *Polymorph,* which is currently affecting the target:

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies.

Comment: Great answer, the specifc beats general rule is PHB 7 and the Action rules can be found in the MM 11 (recharge is on MM 12).